# Discover a priodic pattern in a signal

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I have a large sequence of numbers c.a 10000 and I want to find a priodic pattern in this sequence of numbers. Could you please point me some references or hints to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should determine the length of the periodic pattern. This can be easily made with a Fourier-transformation. Look for frequences with high amplitude. This are candidates for the length of the periodic pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, actually I did it, I have calculated amplitude for datas, but I dont know exactly what shouls I do as next step. Do you have any example or references in this field? I am really new in this field :/

Comment: Are you looking for exact same patterns, or only nearly same ones. If you are looking for exactly the same patterns, simply take an interval of the calculated length.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of possible algorithms. Wikipedia lists some [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_detection). Although the field is very wide, I hope that will give you a starting point.